# Full Page Image is not working in react js

Tags: css, reactjs

Guys I'm trying to make a responsive background for my page, but nothing is rendered, I'm following the tutorial below but nothing works, the imports are correct, I did the test by pasting a string between the div and a small strip of the image was drawn at the top of the page just to cover the string I put in the div, follow my code below.

Tutorial : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_full_page

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="bg"></div>
    );
}
```

**App.css**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url(images/slide1.jpg);

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: the image url is definitely going to need to be a string, so that's the first thing, put some quotes around it and make sure the path is correct

Comment: That's actually not correct, Dan. In CSS this syntax is allowed, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url().

Comment: @DanOswalt added '' in the path but nothing is rendered.

Comment: hm, css gets me again. i'll see myself out

Comment: how are you loading App? are you seeing this `div.bg` when you inspect in the dev tools?

Comment: @DanOswalt I can see the div.bg in the preview, I did a test and when passing the height and widht in px the image was drawn, in this case my height 100% is not working, however if it works for height 300px.

Comment: not a react expert, but I'm wondering if the body and html styles need to be outside of the app.css. body and html tags are global styles, which shouldn't go into component styles. maybe an "index.css" for global css, and put the body and html css there.

Comment: or forget the body and html styles altogether and try `height: 100vh` on the bg class

Comment: @DanOswalt replacing 100% with 100vh and deleting the body and html slyle worked perfectly, thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: great! glad it worked